# ghc 8.0 cabal build error "ld: -r and -pie may not be used together" known?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

After upgrading to ghc 8.0 on a *RECENT* ubuntu machine, I got the following build error:

> /usr/bin/ld: -r and -pie may not be used together

A different error message for the same problem is:

> relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a > shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Is this a known bug? Are there other solutions?

Comment: This question is for saving the 3 hours of work for searching for a solution (I wasted 3 hours...)

Comment: Since you know a solution, could you post it as an answer for better visibility? Thanks! (Answering your own question is perfectly reasonable, although there might be a timeout stopping you in the first 15 minutes after you post a question.)

Comment: Did what you suggested, answered my own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The solution is to use the linker flag "-no-pie":**

```
cabal -v --ghc-option="-optl-no-pie" install cabal-install
```

Is suspect it is perhaps an implicit LD flag that is set on ubuntu that is conflicting somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is an incredibly! hacky solution, but it did get me past the immediate problem of not being able to build grub. It should work for any other app, but it's so! hacky, I wouldn't leave this in place for very long.

I realize the poster's question is about cabal, not grub. But the problem affects multiple programs and the "correct" solution of using the -fno-pie compiler flag doesn't actually work. Apparently the latest version of gcc sets "pie" on by default, and this takes precedence over the -fno-pie flag. Or at least sometimes.

Here is my working hack for gcc version 6.2.0-5ubuntu12, lubuntu 16.10 (yakkety), linux kernel 4.8.0-22... to build grub 2.02~beta3:

```
# TO HACK
sudo cp /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc.orig
sudo cp /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc.patch
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc.patch /usr/bin/gcc
sudo bless /usr/bin/gcc.patch
# search and replace "-pie -z now" with "-v   -z now" (see below)
# save changes and exit 'bless'
```

That is, use the 'bless' hex editor to search for the text string **-pie -z now** and change that string to read **-v   -z now**   making sure to replace "pie" with "v space space" so it takes up the EXACT same number of characters.

What this does is hack the compiler into sending -v to the linker instead of -pie. If you want to see for yourself what the compiler's doing, just include -Q -v in your compiler's CFLAGS list, and read closely. Even if you specify -fno-pie, the dang thing will still toss out a -pie option to the linker. Anyway, be sure to put everything back when you're done.

```
# UNDO THE HACK
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/gcc.orig /usr/bin/gcc
```

.

```
# REDO THE HACK
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/gcc.patch /usr/bin/gcc
```