# Incremental Linking with CMake (GCC/CLANG)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, clang, incremental-build

I am aware that incremental linking is not a compiler feature, but a linker feature. In the past, I have used MSVC's incremental linking (`/INCREMENTAL`) and now I want to use it in my project that compiles with `clang` (or `gcc` if need be). My project consists of three static libraries (A, B, and C) and one executable (D). As a side note, D depends B and C, while C depends on A and B.

From my understanding, all I have to do is pass `-Wl,-i` to the linker (CMake uses `ld` by default) as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42245394/3740613). My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
set(LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-i")

add_library(A)
target_link_options(A PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE libSomeLib.so)


add_library(B)
target_link_options(B PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})

add_library(C)
target_link_options(C PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})

add_executable(D)
target_link_libraries(D PRIVATE libSomeOtherLib.so C B A)
target_link_options(D PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})
```

However, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: -r and -pie may not be used together
```

I then decided to run `/usr/bin/ld --help` and search for these flags. I saw that `-r, -i, --relocatable` are explained as `Generate relocatable output`.

Changing to `-Wl,-i,-nostdlib,-nostartfiles`,`-Wl,-i,-nostdlib,-nostartfiles,-no-pie` or `-Wl,-r` (or any combination of these flags) does not change the error message.

However, if I remove `-Wl` and just use `-r`, I get `/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object libSomeOtherLib.so`.

My questions are:

1. Is my understanding of incremental linking correct? Can I use it in CMake with `ld`?
2. Why does the error message change when not using `-Wl`?
3. I wrote a hello world program to eliminate all dependencies (static and shared libraries). When compiling with `clang++ main.cpp -Wl,-i -o main` I still get `/usr/bin/ld: -r and -pie may not be used together`. Why?
4. Is it possible to use incremental linking in my case, especially with may chain of static and shared dependencies?
5. Do I need to pass `-Wl` flags to all targets or is it enough to set them just for my executable?

**Edit:**

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) says that `target_link_libraries` *cannot be used to add options for static library targets, since they do not use a linker*, so I have removed them from my `CMakeLists.txt` (the original code is still present in the question for clarity).

Removing all `target_link_options` (for the three static libraries as seen stated in the documentation) and `target_link_options(D PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})` for the executable doesn't solve anything. My generator is `ninja` and I can see the build commands in `build.ninja`. When looking at the flags, I only see that `-Wl,-i` is only passed to the executable (`LINK_FLAGS = -Wl,-i`), while the three static libraries have no linker flags (explained in the documentation). So I need `target_link_options(D PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})` to somehow pass `-Wl,-i` to the linker.

When passing `-Wl,-i` to `set_property(TARGET A PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS ${INCREMENTAL_LINKING})`, I see that `ar` is called for each static library and it outputs `/usr/bin/ar: invalid option -- 'W'`.

Current `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-i")

add_library(A)
set_property(TARGET A PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS ${INCREMENTAL_LINKING})
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE libSomeLib.so)

add_library(B)
set_property(TARGET B PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS ${INCREMENTAL_LINKING})

add_library(C)
set_property(TARGET C PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS ${INCREMENTAL_LINKING})

add_executable(D)
target_link_libraries(D PRIVATE libSomeOtherLib.so C B A)
target_link_options(D PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})
```

Comment: Remove `target_link_options(D PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})`.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't work. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Have you tried to additionally pass `-Wl,-no-pie`, as suggested by [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39112399/3440745) for the similar error message?

Comment: Yes. I still get the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250190/can-i-get-cmake-to-generate-makefiles-utilizing-gcc-incremental-linking

Comment: So I guess incremental linking is only for MSVC? I have also read the post you commented here, but it conflicts with the other posts I have seen. This is why I asked this question. Anyway, I updated the question.